# Any downside of using `UTM` tags for backlinks to my site?

Tags: google-analytics, utm-parameters

Ive been trying to get more information from google analytics about our website referral sources, but like most people 90% of the traffic is showing up a "direct".

To get around this for links that i can control, eg things like social media profile / bio links etc.. i want to tag the links with a `UTM` tag so i will be able to get more info on the traffic in Google Analytics.

Is there any downside from a backlink / SEO / or other perspective of making as many links as i can have a unique `UTM` tag ?

Answer (score 3):

Any parameter in the URL (including UTMs) could force the search engine to crawl it, so to avoid a lot of duplicate content indexed, we should direct the search engines to the option we prefer as the main one.

As [John stated](https://twitter.com/williamvicary/status/1444066621837004802), the canonicalization process it's not only using the `canonical` tag. We must be consistent with all the signals.

> Canonicalization uses a number of factors (redirects, rel-canonical,
> internal/external links, sitemaps, more) -- the more you can get them
> to align, the more likely your input will be followed.

Although duplicate content doesn’t cause your site to be penalized, using parameters at a large scale could affect your SEO results.

Comment: If the link accepts it, place the utm parameters after a hash (#) instead of a ?. GA supports it and it does not alter the crawled URL. https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/27817601/to-hash-or-not-to-hash?hl=en